# Is snowflake net connector thread safe?

Tags: c#, .net, http, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Regarding the snowflake .NET connector: https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net, I can find nothing in the documentation or source code to suggest that connection pooling is supported, and because the connection itself is backed by `HttpClient`, and we know that `HttpClient` [should be reused rather than created/disposed constantly](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/), what's the best way to use the snowflake .NET connector when you'll be making many queries across threads?

Note: I'm not planning on changing any properties of the connection once it's created (schema, database, etc.).

For example:

```
// application startup registers this provider as a singleton
public class SnowflakeConnectionProvider : IDisposable
{
  private IDbConnection _conn;

  public SnowflakeConnectionProvider()
  {
    _conn = new SnowflakeDbConnection();
    _conn.ConnectionString = "connectionString";
    _conn.Open();
  }

  public IDbConnection conn { get => _conn; }

  public Dispose() => _conn.Close();
}
```

Now, is it safe for multiple threads to share the one `SnowflakeDbConnection` like so:

```
public class Worker
{
  public Worker(SnowflakeConnectionProvider provider)
  {
    IDbConnection conn = provider.conn;
    
    IDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from t";
    IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                
    while(reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(0));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why the downvotes? If I’m making bad assumptions or writing bad code / asking a bad question, I’d appreciate knowing why so that I can learn.

Comment: When in doubt, assume it isn't thread-safe.

Comment: That’s fair. If it’s not thread safe, is the only way forward manually managing a pool of connections? We can’t simply open a new connection for each query without risking socket exhaustion.

Comment: I don't know, sorry.  This may be a question to raise with the Snowflake developers.  If nothing else, it might prompt them to improve their documentation accordingly.

Comment: I see a similar question was opened on github, check later: https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net/issues/275. Also this is a good place to note that the JDBC connector is indeed thread-safe.  `Connection is thread-safe and it can be shared by multiple statements.` https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-jdbc/issues/3 -- I'm not sure about the .net tho.

Comment: Summary from github: The .net client is thread-safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Summary from GitHub: The connector is thread safe.

> As long as you do not use any session variables in your snowflake code, you can have multiple threads sharing the same SnowflakeDbConnection. It does not matter if you are reusing threads or if you are creating new threads all the time.

> Even if you are constantly creating and disposing connections from multiple different threads, a single HttpClient is created once and then reused and shared by all connections.

https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net/issues/275